# IMAP authentication with Courier throws error

Tags: email, postfix, courier, courier-imap

I've just set-up PostFix + Courier + Roundcube using the following site for my instrcutions: http://flurdy.com/docs/postfix/

I was attempting to log into my webmail and it failed.

Checking the logs I was directed to look at the IMAP setup and it appears that's where the issue is

I've done the following:

- Checked that logs were enabled in /etc/courier/authdaemonrc
- Run the following commands

  ```
  me@mybox:/var/log/roundcube$ telnet localhost 143
  Trying 127.0.0.1...
  Connected to localhost.
  Escape character is '^]'.
  OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UIDPLUS CHILDREN NAMESPACE THREAD=ORDEREDSUBJECT
  THREAD=REFERENCES SORT QUOTA IDLE ACL ACL2=UNION STARTTLS]
  Courier-IMAP ready.  Copyright 1998-2011 Double Precision, Inc.  See COPYING for distribution information.

  a login username password
  BYE Temporary problem, please try again later
  Connection closed by foreign host.`
  ```

Where else can I look for errors or information on why this isn't working?

EDIT:
Checked the logs and found a typo in a config
I now get the following

```
May  5 00:25:09 ip-172-31-23-199 imapd: 
me@example.com: No such file or directory
```

Edit 2:
That sent the correct data; however, roubdcube is looking for data to be in var/mail/virtual/psukardi/new

While it's showing up in /home/psukardi/Maildir/new

Comment: Check /var/log/mail.log?

Comment: Have you created  the mailbox directory for the user? Did the directory existed?

Comment: I thought this was taken care of via postfix virtual directories is this not the case?  I also tried adding a userby doing 

sudo useradd -m -s /bin/bash new.person

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you follow [the tutorial](http://flurdy.com/docs/postfix/), you might notice that the author use MySQL as user Database. So, if you create new user, you can insert it in MySQL table.

Now, the next part is creating Maildir folder. You have two options here

1. Send email to new account and let postfix `virtual` agent to create the maildir for you.
2. Use [`maildirmake`](http://www.courier-mta.org/maildirmake.html) utility from courier.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know about the maildirmake utli.  Thanks!